# Calling component function from inside React Navigation navigator using params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Using React Nav v4, Im trying to set params in ComponentA.js ...

```
componentDidMount(){
    ...

    this.props.navigation.setParams({ 
        goToTop: this.goToTop.bind(this) 
    });

}
```

and call them from my initNavigator.js in createBottomTabNavigator > tabBarOnPress

```
const MainTabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
HomeStack: {
    screen: HomeCard,
    navigationOptions: (navigation, navigationOptions) => ({

        ...,
        tabBarOnPress: ({navigation, defaultHandler}) => {
            const { isFocused, state, goBack, routes } = navigation;

            // NEED TO CALL HERE

        },
```

I've tried navigation.getParam('goToTop', 'someDefult')

```
Logs someDefult
```

console.log(navigation.state)

```
{ 
isTransitioning: false,
index: 0,
key: 'HomeStack',
routeName: 'HomeStack',
params: undefined,
routes: 
[ { routeName: 'Home',
    key: 'id-1567452719174-1',
    params: { goToTop: [Function: bound ] } } ] }
```

Also is there a reason why params is undefined but routes params contain the function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolved** by calling state.routes[0].params.goToTop();

```
const MainTabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
HomeStack: {
    ...
    ...
    navigationOptions: (navigation, navigationOptions) => ({

        ...,
        tabBarOnPress: ({navigation, defaultHandler}) => {
            const { isFocused, state, goBack, routes } = navigation;

            // NEED TO CALL HERE
            state.routes[0].params.goToTop();

        },
```